# GDB Cygwin will not redirect output to file

Tags: c++, gdb, cygwin

I have a "hello World" project called test.
I do

gdb test
r > log.txt

I gethttp://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

```
(gdb) r > log.txt
Starting program: /usr/bin/test > log.txt
[New Thread 6408.0x1454]
[New Thread 6408.0x1198]
[New Thread 6408.0x1458]
[New Thread 6408.0x1504]
[New Thread 6408.0xef0]
/usr/bin/test: missing argument after 'log.txt'
[Thread 6408.0x1198 exited with code 2]
[Thread 6408.0x1458 exited with code 2]
[Thread 6408.0x1504 exited with code 2]
[Inferior 1 (process 6408) exited with code 02]
(gdb)
```

I am using GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 7.10.1-1) 7.10.1

What is wrong?

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to rediret std output to a file with the name log.txt, but as you can see all I get is an error message.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html

Comment: That is about logging from gdb commands and not a programs output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on cygwin

```
touch log.txt 
gdb wc
tty log.txt
run cygcheck.out
quit

cat  log.txt
  973  2919 73904 cygcheck.out
```

If the output file does not exist the command tty fails, so the `touch`